# How to configure spring boot for using klaxon library

Tags: json, spring-boot, kotlin, spring-restcontroller, klaxon

There is a [klaxon library](https://github.com/cbeust/klaxon) - JSON parser for `kotlin`

How to configure `Spring Boot` for using it to make a REST API in this way:

```
@RestController
class SampleController {

  @RequestMapping("/test", method = [RequestMethod.POST])
  fun test(@RequestBody body:JsonObject): JsonObject {
      //work with body val (KLAXON object)
      //return KLAXON object
  }
}
```

`@RequestBody body:JsonObject` - is a Klaxon object, so we do not want to use standard `Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder` for RequestBody. For simplicity we do not want to use it for Response body too.
Post body is some kind of dynamic data, so I want to use a `Low level API` in lib, not a `Object binding API`.

Answer (score 0):

No, at the moment it's not possible.

[Reference](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/13229)